# How do I use InputScope PhraseList or EnumString on Windows Phone 7 textbox?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7

I have found plenty of tutorials demonstrating InputScope values of email, phone number, name, etc.  But nothing that addresses my specific problem.

I want the user to be able to select a value from an enum or a list of strings.  I'm trying to imitate the behavior found in the emulator under Settings > region & language, for either the short date or long date values.  Basically, when the user clicks in the textbox a list is presented from which the user can select a value, which then populates the textbox.  In one case, the list is presented full screen, in the other case the list is presented in place of the textbox.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all the InputScopes are supported, yet! It appears that PhraseList is one such scope.

This should be fixed (and hopefully better documented) in the RTM.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of options for this.

The closest match to your requirements is Alex's picker box. Details here for your reference.

[Implementing Picker Box functionality on WP7. - Alex Yakhnin's Blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/priozersk/implementing-picker-box-functionality-on-wp7)

Also note with the release of the tools is a context menu implemented in the Windows Phone Toolkit. Details here for your reference.

[Pining for Windows Phone 7 controls? We got ya covered! [Announcing the first release of the Silverlight for Windows Phone Toolkit!] - Delay's Blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/delay/pining-for-windows-phone-7-controls-we-got-ya-covered-announcing-the-first-release-of-the-silverlight-for-windows-phone-toolkit)